# Pass POST data to two php files

Tags: php, html, post, web

Hello I'm hoping this will be an easy fix.

To simply put it, I want to do the following:

1) Have a form that users input data (estimate.html) and submit to validate.php

2) From validate.php, check the POST data and if everything is ok, the user presses the submit button which then sends the same exact POST data to submission.php.

Is there any easy way to send the same exact POST data from the original form throughout my two php files? (Hopefully without sessions)

```
estimate.html -> validate.php -> submission.php
```

---

What I have right now:

I have a form that can have an unknown amount of fields that can be passed into validate.php.

I have already validated all the entries in the POST data sent to validate.php. If all data validates successfully, then rather than inserting all data into hidden fields and resubmitting the data to submission.php, can I just resend the POST that was sent validate.php?

Comment: what does your validate.php has.. another form?.. you can always output the data and than take that data and post again.. or use session of course.. also what does your submission do different than validate.. if you can you should always implement both functionality in one file.

Comment: You can do it using Session successfully. You just need to save the post data to a session variable and redirect to submission.php

Comment: I think ajax is the best option,use callback on validate.php request is completed

Comment: Sessions is the better option.

Comment: validate.php allows the user to view their project and it also allows me to alert them if anything is incorrect. There is no form on the validate and the submission page. Validate is for view, submission is for actually inserting the data into the database.

Comment: Using php to validation data forces you to reload the page every time you want validate. I suggest you use ajax for validation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Using session only or hidden fields. I guess..

You can also use array in hidden to reduce the size of elements.

```
<input type="hidden" value="array('username'=>'user','password'=>'password');">
```

something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could either move the post data to the session superglobal when it is received in validate.php

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
```

This will then make that variable available to any subsequent php page run in that session by the client until it is unset.

Alternatively you can use hidden input in the form containing the submit button

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="<?php echo $_POST['password']; ?>">
<input type="button" ... >
etc
```

It depends on the scope of where you want this data to be available.

You can also build in the confirmation page into the final page where you simply resubmit to the same page with an extra confirmation post variable asserted which you can check for and proceed if it is.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of ensuring that the data posted to `submission.php` is the same as posted to `validate.php`:

1. You can post data to `submission.php` from within `validate.php` using PHP:

   ```
   $data = file_get_contents('php://input');

   $options = array('http' =>
       array(
           'method'  => 'POST',
           'content' => $data,
       )
   );

   $context = stream_context_create($options);
   $result = file_get_contents('submission.php', false, $context);
   ```
2. You can return a hash of the POSTed data to the client, whid would be attached to the POST to the `submission.php`. The hash should contain the posted data and a secred key shared by `validate.php` and `submission.php`. The latter should then recalculate the hash of the input data to check if the data are validated.