# How to send data from the PHP file1 to PHP file 2 that inculdes JSON code?

Tags: php, json, api

I am new in API`s, so I have created two .php files:

1- file1.php (Includes the HTML form to get data from the user **example:** code and description inputs)

2- file2.php (Includes the Json code that take an input and return output Msg)

**Example:**

file2.php should have the below Json format:

```
{
"STATUS_CODE" : "AP 2013",
"STATUS_DESCRIPTION" : "Amazing Pi3232",
}
```

After executing the Json format from Postman or JMeter, the below result will occurs:

```
{"message":"Status was created."}
```

**Question:**

How can I send the above Input from file1.php to file2.php and how to retreive the returned message from the API?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16539928/2871356

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have used this and it works fine thank you dear.

```
//Submit Form with Form fields              
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#SubmitFormSeetStatus").click(function(){

                // Show that Feedback something is loading
                // $("#Loading").show();
                $("#Loading").html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

                //To debug
                //alert("You've clicked the link.");


                 //Send Json format to Create a Seed Status and get the response
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Path of the .php file',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 
                        'STATUS_CODE': $("#STATUS_CODE").val(), 
                        'STATUS_DESCRIPTION': $("#STATUS_DESCRIPTION").val(),
                        'STATUS_ALT_DESCRIPTION': $("#STATUS_ALT_DESCRIPTION").val(),
                        'STATUS_ACTIVE': $("#STATUS_ACTIVE").val(),

                    }),

                    processData: false,
                    success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){

                        // Get Json response as a string
                        var JsonResponse= JSON.stringify( data );

                        //Get response as Json format to be able to get each value
                        var obj = JSON.parse(JsonResponse);

                            //To debug
                            //var p = obj.message;
                            //console.log( p );

                        //Print Object value inside the html by specific key
            document.getElementById("Successalertmsg").innerHTML = obj.message;

                        $("#alertmsgfeedback").show();

                        //$('#response').html( $JsonResponse );
                        $("#Loading").hide();
                    },
                    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                        console.log( errorThrown );
                        alert( "Some fields are empty please fill them!");
                        $("#Loading").hide();

                    }
                });
            });
        });
```